# How do I add local SDK to Xamarin forms app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, sdk

I am currently developing an app in Xamarin forms and I need to add an SDK. My SDK is from Tuya and it is downloaded locally but I dont know how to add it to the project. I appreciate all answers.

Comment: https://support.tuya.com/en/help/_detail/K8sdy1js3ujaa

Comment: Ohh no, shit i suppose i have to re-do the entire project on xcode and in Android Studio

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/